# How to generate xsd from wsdl in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, wsdl, soapui

How to generate xsd from wsdl in node js

We have a requirement to validate a request with the associated XSD in node js.

I found one npm which does the job called "xsd-schema-validator" which requires xsd but i only have WSDL, not xsd "can anyone please help me on how to generate xsd from WSDL in nodejs"

Thank you.

Comment: WSDLs carry their XML Schema, or at least a link to this, in the `<types>` element. You should have it already. Also, this question has been tagged `soapui`: is that relevant? Even so, if you import a WSDL, soapUI gives you some handy views onto the different components of the WSDL.

Comment: thanx for replying, yes as you said wsdl has link in the <types> section ,can you please tell me how to extract that xsd from wsdl

Comment: Just plug that link into a browser or import the WSDL into soapUI and go to the interface viewer.

Comment: no i can't do that, i have to perform this using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you have a URL to your XML Schema, you can use something like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to follow the link:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');     

fetch('https://location-of-schema')      
 .then(res => res.text())         
 .then(body => console.log(body));
```

Check the [node-fetch documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) for more options in dealing with what you get back (save to a file, process on the fly, ...).

Now, you can use your [xsd-schema-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xsd-schema-validator) to validate your payload against the fetched XML Schema.